# I'm facing error "Cannot resolve method 'parse' in 'object' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

here is the code and screenshot can someone help me

```
private Object Uri;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String str= editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Uri webpage = Uri.parse(str);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your `import` statement for `Uri`?

Comment: import android.net.Uri;

Comment: @SaiyafJadoon no doubt this -> private Object Uri; is giving you trouble

Comment: Yes, remove `private Object Uri;`

Comment: And replace it with `private Uri uri;`